# How to return a list from list of list in scheme?

Tags: scheme, nested-lists, paradigms

I am trying to return from 
`'('(animal '(name a b c) '(age 1 2 3) '(family x y z))` only `'(name age family)`. How do I do that? I was trying this:

```
(car(apply append(cons (cadr (car list)) '())))
```

but I get an error.

Comment: what implementation are you using? can you give us a snippet on tio.run or ideone.com, defining your data at least?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the list you want to handle is:

```
'('(animal '(name a b c) '(age 1 2 3) '(family x y z)) or

'(animal (name a b c) (age 1 2 3) (family x y z))
```

The latter one makes more sense to me. Your (sub) problem is to return a list containing all first elements of sublists. You may need to use recursion. Something like:

```
(define get_list_of_first
    (lambda (lol)
        (if (null? lol) '()
            (cons (car (car lol)) (get_list_of_first (cdr lol)))
        )
    )
)
```

This is a very basic example to learn Scheme. You need to use the above function to continue your assignment (I guess). Have fun.

Comment: It is the first one, because my actual list is somethng loke '( '(animal '(name a b c) '(age 1 2 3) '(family x y z)) '(fruits '(name a b c) '(colour x y z) (price 1 2 3))). And I have to return the characteristics of an type, eg for fruits it will be '(name colour price)

Comment: No different.  Still the same subproblem concept.